# Обновление маркеров в Google Maps

Tags: google-maps-api, xmlparser, javascript

Привет, 
Я новичек в JavaScript, и вот задачка у меня :)
После удаления маркеров, хочу обновлять маркеры автоматически в Google Maps.
Нашел хорошиий пример, но он для JSON, а у меня XML.
Хочу изменить код, думаю надо сделать изменения здесь: "res=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);"

Буду рад любой подсказки.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
var markers=new Array();
update();

function update(){
    var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=((window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            res=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //clear existing markers
            for (x=0;x<markers.length;x++) {
                markers[x].setMap(null);
            }
            markers=new Array();
            //draw new markers
            for(i=0;i<res['bus'].length;i++){
                var a=new Object();
                //change these lines to match with your XML
                a.lat=res.bus[i]['lat'];
                a.lng=res.bus[i]['lng'];
                var point=new google.maps.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng);
                bounds2.extend(point);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,map: map});
                markers.push(marker);
            }
            setTimeout(update,2000);

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","myDataSource.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Собирай маркеры в массив. Ключ доступа к маркеру в массиве должен быть какой-либо уникальный идентификатор.

При изменении положения маркера тебе его нужно полностью перерисовать (Удалить, нарисовать с новыми координатами).

1. У тебя трашно реализован AJAX. Нет проверок ни на статус ответа, ни на response.
2. Будь мужиком, использую json-ы для обмена.

Comment: спасибо за ответ, буду копать и учится :)

Comment: Да AJAX ужасен. @AlexWebs, чтобы не плодить велосипеды и придавать коду хорошую читабельность, рекомендую посмотреть в сторону [JQuery][1]. В сети масса примеров как он применяется на практике. С гугло-картами не конфликтует, проверено практикой.

  [1]: http://jquery.com/

Comment: спасибо KiTE